# acces eventlistener in a created button in dom

Tags: javascript

edited with all the code, sorry for my messy coding, I am begginer

hope you can help with this,
 I have just created a button in the dom with a function, I gave the button a class to apply an event listener, for some reason i am not able to activate the listener, does anyone have a clue about what I am doing wrong?

```
//this is th initial array of items, after I am changing it to an arrayof objects
let shoppingList = ['banana','apples','cherries','oranges', 'peaches'];
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

//this is the last thing I need, create new items and allow the del button
const foo=()=>{
console.log('hi');
}


const adder =(item, index, price,name)=>{

    list.innerHTML += `<div class='item${[index+1]}'>${name}, price ${price} </div>`;
    item[index]= {name,price};
    const delElm = document.createElement('button');//the element to remove items
    delElm.className = 'remove';
    delElm.innerHTML = 'X';
    list.appendChild(delElm);

    const btndel = document.querySelector('.remove')
    console.log(btndel)

    btndel.addEventListener('click', foo)

}
//assign a random price to the original array
for (let i = 0; i < shoppingList.length; i++) {

    let prices = i+Math.round((((Math.random()*5)+10))*100)/100;
    let name = shoppingList[i];
    adder(shoppingList,i,prices,name);

}

const btnElm= document.querySelector('.press');

//function to add new elements
const addItm=()=>{

    const nameElm = document.querySelector('#text');
    const priceElm = document.querySelector('#price');
    let name = nameElm.value;
    let prices = Number(priceElm.value);

    let i = shoppingList.length-1;

    adder(shoppingList, i, prices,name)

    console.log(shoppingList)

}

console.log(shoppingList)


btnElm.addEventListener('click', addItm)
```

edit with the HTML, basically, the user can add new items filling the form, each item should be posible to be removed,

```
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="name item">
<input type="text" id="price" placeholder="price">
    <button class="press">add</button> -->
```

thanks you in advance

Comment: Not sure if its a typo or your actual code, but in your foo function, hi is missing a quote.

Comment: corrected, it was a mistake while copying the code, but still not working, anyway thank you very much for your interest, :)

Comment: are you calling the `adder` function anywhere?

Comment: I guess you should share as well the affected HTML to have some context.

Comment: yes, it is being called in the function  addItm, and in the for at the begining

Comment: Do you have any runtime errors ?

Comment: not errors sadly in the console, :(